# Estimate computational cost of a sorting algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Today, my algorithm teacher gave me a little exercise in introducing computational cost. The code is as follows:

```
A = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
for y in range (0, len(A)):
   el = A[y]
   i = y-1
   while i >= 0 and A[i] > el:
      A[i+1] = A[i]
      i = i-1
   A[i+1] = el
```

Without wasting your time: it is an algorithm that takes an array and reorders it. I have to find out what order is O. Considering that all assignment operations use 1 as a cost, the "heaviest" lines are the for and the while. If the for loop is of the order of O (n) with n = len (A) I can't figure out how to calculate the while. Worst case it runs 28 times, but I can't find a correlation with the length of the array. Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given input the condition `A[i] > el` will always be true when it gets evaluated, as every next value `el` is less than all preceding values `A[i]`. So the input really triggers a worst case execution.

Then the number if executions of the inner loop increases with one every time the outer loop makes an iteration:

```
0
1
2
3
...
n-1
```

The sum of all these is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number): n(n-1)/2, which is O(n²)

Answer (score 0):

The while loop inserts `A[y]` (for some `y`) in the subarray `A[0..y-1]` before it. As you can verify, when performed on increasing `y`, this makes `A[0..y]` sorted. The cost of the while loop is proportional to the distance between `y` and the insertion point. At best, this distance is always `1` (`A[y]` already in place); at worst, it is `y` (`A[y]` should come first, as on the given input); on average, `y/2` for a uniform distribution.

Hence, globally, the sort is at best `Θ(n)`, but at worst and on average `Θ(n²)`. (Sum of integers up to `n`.)